# Change the font colour in all cells of a list of Excel sheets

Tags: excel, vbscript

I am trying to change the font colour of cells in a list of Excel sheets from red to black.

The code reads the file paths from a txt file then puts them into an array. Then using the array checks the Excel sheet for red font colour and changes it to black.

It isn't working and I have limited knowledge of VBscript.

```
REM Attribute VB_Name = "Module1"
Sub SimpleMacro()
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    objExcel.Visible = True

    Const ForReading = 1 

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Set objTextFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile _ 
    ("pathlist.txt", ForReading) 

    Do Until objTextFile.AtEndOfStream 
        strNextLine = objTextFile.Readline 
        arrServiceList = Split(strNextLine , ",") 
        Wscript.Echo "Server name: " & arrServiceList(0) 
        For i = 1 to Ubound(arrServiceList) 
            Wscript.Echo "Service: " & arrServiceList(i) 
        Next
    Loop

    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(arrServiceList)
    Set objWorksheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

    RedColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    BlackColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)

    'Get number of rows in the specified column
    RowsCount = Range("A1" *.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

    'Select cell
    Range("A1" *.End(xlDown)).Select

    'Loop the cells
    For x = 1 To RowsCount
        If ActiveCell.Font.Color = RedColor Then
            'Change the text color
            ActiveCell.Font.Color = BlackColor
        Else
            ActiveCell.Font.Color = BlackColor
        End If

        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Specifics please?

Comment: `xlDown` will be unknown as you are late binding, add `Const xlDown = -4121` after `Const ForReading = 1`. Aside from that describe how it fails.

Comment: Sorry for being so vague. When I run it, it doesn't change the font colours from red to black. So there is a list of file paths in pathlist.txt that it should read the file paths from the array and then go into them and look for red coloured font and change them to black.

Comment: To see the error if any, open excel, press ALT+F11, paste the above code barring the lines related to objExcel. i.e. `Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = True` and omit references to `objExcel` from the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use something like `*.End(xlDown)`. Not only is the constant undefined in VBScript, but there's also no keyword/variable `*`. You can set the font color of a specific column to black like this:

```
objWorksheet.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Font.Color = BlackColor
```

or the font color of the used range like this:

```
objWorksheet.UsedRange.Font.Color = BlackColor
```

For changing the color of all cells where the font color is red you can use something like this:

```
For Each cell In objWorksheet.Cells
  If cell.Font.Color = RedColor Then cell.Font.Color = BlackColor
Next
```

Another thing: you can open multiple workbooks by using an array of paths:

```
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(arrServiceList)
```

but in that case the array should contain only paths to Excel workbooks, nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for that tho I need it to only change red coloured font to black not just turn all the font colour to black.

Comment: The code you have changes the cell color to black if it's red, and also if it's not red.

Comment: Oh sorry that was just trying to see it was working its not meant to be there.

Comment: No that last one didn't work, it might be that the path list part isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

I am presuming that you want to change the font colors only in column A. The following is correct VBA, which I hope will be correct VBScript as wll.

```
lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
For i = 1 To lastrow
   If Range("A" & i).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) Then
        Range("A" & i).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)      'you can substitute your color variables in
   End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

This will turn All and only cells with red fonts to black font. And will do this without using a loop or any comparison statements, providing very fast reliable code.

```
Sub Sample()
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

Dim lngLastFilePathRow As Long

lngLastFilePathRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A1:A" & lngLastFilePathRow)
     'Filter Out Everything that does NOT have Red font
    .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0 _
        , 0), Operator:=xlFilterFontColor
    'With only the cells that have Red font change the color to black
    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .AutoFilter
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this is great, is there any way of then inputting the array `arrServiceList` so that it goes thru the file path list?

Comment: Use what you have up to the Line `RedColor = RGB(255, 0, 0)` Then finish with my answer, but add the workbook and worksheet (objWorkbook , objWorksheet) references to my ranges.

Comment: Thanks a lot I'll give it a go and get back to you.

Comment: I did what you said but I'm getting an _Expected end of statement_ Error at the line where `Dim lngLastFilePath As long` is. Any ideas?

Comment: @user1839084 The code is VBA, not VBScript. VBScript doesn't support typed variable declarations.

Comment: Sorry I haven't been working on this for the last couple of days. I'll get back onto it soon.